# Mirror Website Content Across Multiple Subdomains

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, multisite, subdomains

I am creating a website that has multiple subdomains depending on the user's city.

I want **everything** except for a few sentences and WooCommerce products to be mirrored across these subdomains. I have been looking through some guides but I cannot find a way to achieve my use case. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

For example "citya.website.org" will sell soap and contain a contact page that is unique to city a. Another subdomain will be called "cityb.website.org" and it will contain a page that is unique to city b.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a network of sites in subdomains or subdirectories using the using the [multisite feature](https://wordpress.org/support/article/create-a-network/). All sites under a multisite network share the same WordPress installation core files, plugins and themes. The individual sites in the network are virtual sites in the sense that they do not have their own directories, but they do have separate directories for media uploads and they do have separate tables in the database, so you can have different Woocommerce products and unique pages in your sub-sites.